# My computer cannot play videos

Tags: ubuntu

I've just installed **UBUNTU** on my computer but it cannot play videos or music .What should I do to solve this problem?????I've tried to download plug-ins but it didn't work I've also tried many solutions and I have gone to many site webs and no solution.

Comment: Saying you've done loads of things is useless information. Telling us WHAT you've done and tried is helpful. Please edit your question and include details of what plugins you've tried, what solutions you've attempted, and any specific messages and errors you've encountered.

Answer (score 0):

Did you install a media player?

```
sudo apt install smplayer
```

See also another StackExchange site: https://askubuntu.com/

Comment: I'll try that one